# Regular expression in JavaScript not the same as in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I have a regular expression to match usernames (which functions in PHP using `preg_match`):

```
/[a-z]+(?(?=\-)[a-z]+|)\.[1-9][0-9]*/
```

This pattern matches usernames of the form `abc.124`, `abc-abc.123`, etc.

However, when I take this to JavaScript:

```
var re = new RegExp("/[a-z]+(?(?=\-)[a-z]+|)\.[1-9][0-9]*/");
```

I receive a syntax error:

```
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /[a-z]+(?(?=-)[a-z]+|).[1-9][0-9]*/: Invalid group
```

The `(?(?=\-)[a-z]+|)` is to say if after `[a-z]+` we see a `-` then assert that `[a-z]+` is after it otherwise, match nothing.  This all works great in PHP, but what am I missing about JavaScript that is different?

EDIT:  I appreciate the comments, and now I have one last question regarding this:

```
    var str="accouts pending removal shen.1206";
    var patt= new RegExp("/[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)?\.[1-9][0-9]*/"); 
    var result=patt.exec(str);
    alert(result);
```

This alert comes up as `null`? But if I do the following it works:

```
var patt=/[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)?\.[1-9][0-9]*/;
var result=patt.exec(str);
alert(result);
```

Why does "new RegExp()" not work?

Comment: Javascript does not support conditionals the `(?` part

Comment: Like most other uses of `new` in JS, I avoid `new RegExp`. Note that both of the answers posted so far are using the literal form rather than `new`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Different regular expression engines support different features. [Conditionals](http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html) are [not supported](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html) by Javascript.

In any event, the conditional is unnecessary for your pattern. I would simplify your expression to `/[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)?\.[1-9][0-9]*/`, which is easier to understand and will work in both PHP's [PCRE](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/intro.pcre.php) and in Javascript.

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript does not use the same regular expression implementation as PHP does. In this case JavaScript does not support the conditional expression `(?(?=regex)then|else)` (see [comparison of regular expression flavors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html)). But you could use the following regular expression that is equivalent to yours:

```
/[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)?\.[1-9][0-9]*/
```

And when using the `RegExp` constructor to create the regular expression (instead of the [regular expression literal syntax `/…/`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)), you need to escape the escaping `\` too. So:

```
var re = /[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)?\.[1-9][0-9]*/;                 // OR
var re = new RegExp("/[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)?\\.[1-9][0-9]*/");
```

Answer (score 2):

Your conditional doesn't work even in PHP.  The lookahead - `(?=-)` - succeeds if the next character is a hyphen, but it doesn't *consume* the hyphen.  Then `[a-z]+` tries to match at the same position and fails, because the next character is still `-`.  You would have to match the hyphen again - `-[a-z]+` - but as the others have said, you shouldn't be using a conditional anyway.

Conditionals are seductive; they *seem* like they should be very useful, but in practice they seldom are.  They lure us in by mirroring the way we naturally think about certain problems: "I want to match some letters, and if the character following them is a hyphen, I want to match it and some more letters."

You'll save yourself a lot of hassle if you learn to think a little more like a regex:  "I want to match a chunk of letters, optionally followed by a hyphen and some more letters."  The regex practically writes itself:

```
/[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)?/
```

(The `\.[1-9][0-9]*` part of your regex was fine; I left it out so I could stay focused on the conditional aspect.)

---

EDIT: To answer the question in the comment, yes, your regex matches strings of both forms: `abc.124` and `abc-abc.123`.  But take a look exactly which *part* of the string it's matching:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => abc.124
            [1] => abc.123
        )

)
```

What happens is that the first `[a-z]+` initially matches the first `abc` in `abc-abc.123`.  Then the lookahead matches the `-` without consuming it and the second `[a-z]+` tries to match the hyphen and fails, as I said earlier.

Having failed to find a match at that position, the regex engine starts bumping ahead one character at a time and trying again.  When it gets to the second `abc`, the first `[a-z]+` matches it and hands off to the next part of the regex, the conditional.

The next character in the input string is `.`, so the lookahead fails.  The conditional isn't required to match anything because you didn't provide a subpattern for the `else` clause.  So the conditional matches nothing and control passes to the next part of the regex, `\.[1-9][0-9]*`, which succeeds.

Comment: php > echo preg_match("/[a-z]+(?(?=\-)[a-z]+|)\.[1-9][0-9]*/","sh-sh.123");  //echos 1

What does that not work for in php ?

Comment: @Chris: see my expanded answer.