# Regex working in JavaScript but not PHP

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I have a signup page for my website.

When the user fills in the form, they get real-time validation through a JavaScript Regex, which works fine. This is done through:

```
var password = document.getElementsByName("password")[0].value;
var pattern = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)([a-zA-Z0-9!\"\#$%&\'()*+,\-.\/:;<=>?@\[\\\]^_`{|}~]{6,})$/;
if(pattern.test(password)){
    document.getElementById("check_password").innerHTML = "Password is valid.";
} else {
    document.getElementById("check_password").innerHTML = "Password is invalid. It should have at least 6 characters, and 1 lowercase letter, uppercase letter, and number.";
}
```

The PHP Regex is used when the user submits the form through this:

```
if(!preg_match("/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)([a-zA-Z0-9!\"\#$%&\'()*+,\-.\/:;<=>?@\[\\\]^_`{|}~]{6,})$/", $_POST["password"])){
        $error = "Password is invalid. It should have at least 6 characters, and 1 lowercase letter, uppercase letter, and number.";
}
```

However, the PHP keeps throwing up the error even when the JavaScript doesn't.  Both regexes are the same and have been tested here in the PHP setting and JavaScript setting. Yet it works in JavaScript but not PHP!

Why does it not work in PHP, and how can I solve the problem?

Comment: What error does it throw. Php does not throw errors for no reason

Comment: you are absolutely sure `$_POST['password']` contains the password?

Comment: @Andreas PHP doesn't throw errors, it's my error messages. Basically, problem is the Regex not matching.

Comment: @Jeff Yes I am sure I have tested it.

Comment: Share problematic input.

Comment: In that case that is because your password does not meet the requirements. I'd say @Jeff probably is correct

Comment: An example would be heHE12. It would match the regex as seen on regex101.com, yet it still does not match in PHP's preg_match()

Comment: @revo isn't that password supposed to be a good password

Comment: @revo Isn't that the reproduction of it? The code says it fails when it should pass! And removing the ! doesn't really make sense.

Comment: It's probably because the regular expression engine differ between Javascript and PHP. I have no idea why it's not working, but this question might point you in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3550178/5503625

Comment: The problem is the backslashes, people.

Comment: I want to check if it DOESN'T MATCH btw

Comment: Because I structured it differently? To be honest do you understnad booleans and if-else statements?

Comment: You don't have to ask. BTW I'm not sure if I understood your problem. If you got your answer that's good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem comes from the backslash. To figure a literal backslash in a php regex string, you need to use 4 backslashes (you need to escape once for the string and once for the regex since it's also a regex special character):

```
if(!preg_match("/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)([a-zA-Z0-9!\"\#$%&\'()*+,\-.\/:;<=>?@\[\\\\\]^_`{|}~]{6,})$/", $_POST["password"])){
    $error = "Password is invalid. It should have at least 6 characters, and 1 lowercase letter, uppercase letter, and number.";
}
```

Note that it is the same if you decide to define your pattern with the RegExp constructor in a Javascript string:

```
var re = new RegExp("^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)([-a-zA-Z0-9!\"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@\\[\\]\\\\^_`{|}~]{6,})$");
```

As an aside, and to avoid the problem, the character class ``` [a-zA-Z0-9!\"\#$%&\'()*+,\-.\/:;<=>?@\[\\\\\]^_``{|}~] ``` can be shorten to `[!-~]`. Also, you don't need a capture group:

```
if(!preg_match("/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[!-~]{6,}$/", $_POST["password"])){
    $error = "Password is invalid. It should have at least 6 characters, and 1 lowercase letter, uppercase letter, and number.";
}
```

To finish, there's a small difference with the anchor `$` between Javascript and PHP. In the two languages it matches the end of the string (by default without the multiline mode), but in PHP it matches also the end of the line when this one is followed by the newline character `\n` just before the end of the string. In other words, the string `"Password0\n"` matches also your pattern because the `$` anchor matches between `0` and `\n` (at the position of `\n`).

To avoid the problem, two possibilities:

- you can use the [D modifier (PCRE_DOLLAR_ENDONLY)](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php):
  `/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[!-~]{6,}$/D`
- or change `$` to `\z` (that matches always and only the end of the string whatever the mode):
  `/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[!-~]{6,}\z/`

Comment: Yes! This is correct. Actually it should be 2 backslashes, as 4 would be pointless as I am trying to include the whole set and 4 would be a waste. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Can you explain why it can be shortened to [!-~]

Comment: @ngmh: it's a simple character range that includes all of your characters, see the ascii table.

Answer (score -1):

You should check if preg_match returns:

Returns INT(0) if not found.
Returns INT(1) if found.
Returns BOOL(false) if an error occurred.

Comment: And I have to use preg_mach() == 0?

Comment: Exactly, you're checking if it returns false, which means if it got an error occurred.

Comment: This answer implicitly promotes a correct solution. Up-vote.

Comment: This isn't actually the problem.

Comment: This is just part of the problem, then.